# What are the 64 Jyotirlinga and their origin?

Tags: shiva, jyotirlinga

I have read in numerous texts that originally there were 64 Jyotirlingas. However, I could not find any list or mention of any Jyotirlinga other than the 12 famous ones.

Further, are all the Jyotirlingas situated in the Indian subcontinent region?
If yes, then why so?
The early Rishis didn't know about the existence of other land masses like America or Africa, just because it was not possible to reach there by foot?

Lastly, is there any significance of the location of the Jyotirlingas?

Comment: Asking about scientific justification of anything is not allowed here. So, you may want that part removed from ur Q. And, welcome to the site!

Comment: Oh, thank you for letting me know that. However, if I want to discuss any scientific interpretations regarding the religion/mythology, where should I try that?

Comment: I don't know .. may be you can try here: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/